# Macbook pro 14" 2021 overexposing when brightness is low

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen

There is an issue on the screen. On some videos (also in images etc...) I've noticed my Macbook pro 14" 2021 overexposes the screen when the brigness is really low. It is very annoying. Here is a recording of the issue:

Here is the screen recording of my issue: https://i.imgur.com/2TgZFIk.mp4
Here is the video of my issue: https://i.imgur.com/y2z7WUD.mp4

youtube video in used in example: https://youtu.be/5rWS705T03s?t=17

I've googled but nothing comes up. How do I prevent my screen overexposing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how this works with an XDR screen & I don't have one in the building to test - but, the youtube video is either in Rec709 or sRGB, both of which are 'non-HDR' formats.

You're trying to expand to full XDR gamut something which simply doesn't have that colour range in it. Test on the lower gamuts, 601, 709 & sRGB - they're more likely to look closer to intended.

As an example, this is what it *should* look like on a fully-calibrated display & workflow. Your original P3 gamut is already 'over-cooking' it.
This is tested on a display calibrated to Adobe RGB, which is a smaller gamut than P3, but wide enough that I can see most of P3. I have a P3 display here but it isn't calibrated [though a quick check on it shows broad agreement.]

[image]

Screenshot of your video so we can directly compare, using the same profile for both.

[image]

Both images are now sRGB, with embedded profile, so we have a level playing field for comparison.

Ordinarily, your display should have a single profile [preset] at which it should be able to auto-map colours correctly. I'm aware this is going to be slightly different for XDR, but also I know the extended range 1600 nit setting is only intended to work on truly 'HDR' images.